# Error insertando objetos en base de datos SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, insert

Muy buenas, estoy intentado insertar objetos en una base de datos **sqlite** pero me da un error que no se muy bien como solucionar

Este es el script de creación de la base de datos:

```
  String CreateDeckQuery = "create table "
                + DECK_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + DECK_ROW_ID_DECK + " integer not null , "
                + DECK_ROW_ID_USER + " integer not null , "
                + DECK_ROW_NAME + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_ONE + " BLOB , "
                + DECK_CARD_TWO + " BLOB , "
                + DECK_CARD_THREE + " BLOB , "
                + DECK_CARD_FOUR + " BLOB , "
                + DECK_CARD_FIVE + " BLOB , "
                + DECK_CARD_SIX + " BLOB , "
                + "FOREIGN KEY (" + MM_ROW_ID_USER + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + TABLE_ROW_ID_USER + ")"
                + ");";
        db.execSQL(CreateDeckQuery);
```

La forma en la que inserto los datos en la tabla:

```
    public void insertDefaultsDecks(int idUser,String deckName,Card cardOne,Card cardTwo,Card cardThree,Card cardFour,Card cardFive,Card cardSix){


    String query = "INSERT INTO " + DECK_TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + DECK_ROW_ID_USER + ","
            + DECK_ROW_NAME + ","
            + DECK_CARD_ONE + ","
            + DECK_CARD_TWO + ","
            + DECK_CARD_THREE + ","
            + DECK_CARD_FOUR + ","
            + DECK_CARD_FIVE + ","
            + DECK_CARD_SIX +
            ") VALUES(" +
            + idUser + ",'"
            + deckName + "',"
            + cardOne + ","
            + cardTwo + ","
            + cardThree + ","
            + cardFour + ","
            + cardFive + ","
            + cardSix +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);


}
```

los datos que intento insertar:

```
        insertDefaultsDecks(c.getInt(0),"Mazo 1",RowToCard(1),RowToCard(1),RowToCard(1),RowToCard(1),RowToCard(1),RowToCard(1));
```

El error que me da:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.cardgameauregpn.damcard, PID: 14732
>                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "{" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO  DeckTable (ID_User,Name,Card_One,Card_Two,Card_Three,Card_Four,Card_Five,Card_Six) VALUES(1,'Mazo 1',Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20});
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
>                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
>                                                                                    at com.cardgameauregpn.damcard.DataBaseManager.insertDefaultsDecks(DataBaseManager.java:409)
>                                                                                    at com.cardgameauregpn.damcard.DataBaseManager.insert(DataBaseManager.java:296)
>                                                                                    at com.cardgameauregpn.damcard.RegisterAndLogin.Register.Register(Register.java:195)

El error concreto:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "{" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO  DeckTable (ID_User,Name,Card_One,Card_Two,Card_Three,Card_Four,Card_Five,Card_Six) VALUES(1,'Mazo 1',Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20},Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1, defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1, attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1, attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20});

Comment: Los valores de CARD en verdad los deseas almacenar en campos tipo BLOB o en realidad deseas tipo TEXT? @Aure_GPN

Comment: Creo que el tipo BLOB es mejor porque CARD es un objeto ,y quiero que al realizar una consulta poder obtener el objeto si fuera un texto no podria obtener el objeto

Comment: En realidad BLOB se usa generalmente para almacenar imagenes no objetos, me parece que hay mal entendido, el tipo de datos que tratas de insertar no podrían insertarse en un campo definido como BLOB .   @Aure_GPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized
>   token: "{" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO DeckTable

estas tratando de agregar un valor como este

> Card{id_Card=1, name='aquarius', heal_Points=1, attack_Points=1,
>   defense_Points=1, magic_Points=1, speed=1, loading_Speed=1,
>   attack_One=1, attack_One_Description='descAttack1', attack_Two=1,
>   attack_Two_Description='descAttack2', photo='aquarius', cost=20}

a un campo definido para valores tipo `BLOB`,

Si deseas insertar en realidad ese tipo de valor te sugiero cambies el tipo a `TEXT`:

```
  String CreateDeckQuery = "create table "
                + DECK_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + DECK_ROW_ID_DECK + " integer not null , "
                + DECK_ROW_ID_USER + " integer not null , "
                + DECK_ROW_NAME + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_ONE + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_TWO + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_THREE + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_FOUR + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_FIVE + " text not null , "
                + DECK_CARD_SIX + " text not null , "
                + "FOREIGN KEY (" + MM_ROW_ID_USER + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + TABLE_ROW_ID_USER + ")"
                + ");";
        db.execSQL(CreateDeckQuery);
```

Es importante que antes de probar nuevamente elimines la aplicación para borrar la estructura actual.

También tendrías que modificar la inserción de datos.

En realidad BLOB se usa generalmente para almacenar imagenes no objetos, me parece que hay mal entendido, el tipo de datos que tratas de insertar no podrían insertarse en un campo definido como BLOB . Ejemplo: https://www.designstring.com/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android/

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Muchas,gracias @Elenasys tranquila,cada vez que tengo que cambiar algo en la base de datos desinstalo e instalo de nueva no se cuentas veces lo habré echo ya jajaja,gracias por tu ayuda , lo probaré en cuanto pueda ya que es un proyecto personal y apenas tengo tiempo,muchas gracias de nuevo,posdata no se quién dio -1 a tu respuesta a mi me aclaro bastante el asunto gracias de nuevo

Comment: Para que no desinstales puedes entrar a aplicaciones buscar tu aplicación y eliminar caché, es lo mismo. Un placer ayudarte,  saludos!